# Recursive Binary Search Function In Python With Issues

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search

I'm working on a recursive binary search for school. Because of the test code, I'm limited to my input being `lyst` and `target` and output should only be a `bool` asserting whether the target was found or not. I've found examples of other questions kind of like mine, but they usually resort to having the upper and lower bounds as part of the input. I can't do that apparently. I'm also unsure as to whether or not I can use a helper function. I will try to find out. This is what I have so far:

```
def binary_search(lyst, target):
    left = 0
    right = len(lyst) - 1

    while left <= right:
        mid = (right + left) // 2
        if len(lyst) == 0:
            return False
        elif lyst[mid] < target:
            left = mid
            return binary_search(lyst[left: right], target)
        elif lyst[mid] > target:
            right = mid
            return binary_search(lyst[left: (right + 1)], target)
        elif lyst[mid] == target:
            return True
    return False
```

It works for some cases, but not all. For example, it will find target of 3 in in the following list `my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, but will not find three in a list of 1-15. I feel like I'm close, but could use a little help.

Comment: *"I can't do that apparently"*: how did that appear to you? BTW: list slicing will kill the benefit of binary search. If you're going to slice, you might as well just look for the target with a linear search.

Comment: This is an inherently iterative problem, so recursion is a bad choice.  But given that you're using recursion, having a loop as well makes no sense.  It's the worst of both worlds.  The only way it will ever loop more than once is if all your `if`/`elif` tests are false.  In that case, the final `else` would be executed, but it's missing.  However, if it reaches the final `elif`, it must be true, so the final `elif` should in fact be an `else`, and the `while` loop should just be an `if` statement, since it can never loop.

Comment: Also keep in mind that a binary search algorithm is expected to run in log(n) time.  That's the whole point of using it.  The list slices that you create when recursing undermine this, causing it to run in linear time.  This means it will run in about the same time as a linear search would.  So this really doesn't qualify as a binary search.

Comment: @Aaron, it's not clear from the question whether recursion is a constraint of the assignment, or something you think you need. Does the assignment *required* you to use recursion?

Comment: Temporarily ignoring the slicing problem, If it's supposed to be recursive then don't use a `while`. It's `while` -or- recursion, not both at once.

Comment: Hey this is great stuff, thanks. I had no idea I would get answers this fast otherwise I would have been a little more attentive. So, @Mark, my instructions don't explicitly say that it's mandatory, they just make reference to the binary search as being recursive in certain parts of the spec, so I'm going to treat it as if it was. The `while` has been changed into an `if` and that makes sense to me. But so if list slicing is out the window, is there a way to make this one work without adding a helper function and without changing the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since recursion is not a requirement, you can just keep track of the start and end indices and stop when they've squeezed together. This avoids the slices while also allowing the function signature to remain unchanged:

```
def binary_search(lyst, target):
    start = 0
    end = len(lyst)
    
    while start < end:
        mid = (end - start) // 2 + start
        if lyst[mid] == target:
            return True
        if target < lyst[mid]:
            end = mid
        else:
            start = mid + 1
    return False


my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

print(binary_search(my_list, 3))
# True

# Some edge cases:
print(binary_search([1], 3))
# False

print(binary_search([], 3))
# False

print(binary_search([3], 3))
# True

print(binary_search([1, 3], 3))
# True
```

If you still want to use recursion with slices you don't need the loop, the recursion takes the place. Everything else is very similar, but in this case you need to deal with the edge case where recursion should stop:

```
def binary_search_rec(lyst, target):
    if not lyst:
        return False

    mid = len(lyst) // 2
    
    if lyst[mid] == target:
        return True
    if target < lyst[mid]:
        return binary_search_rec(lyst[:mid], target)
    else:
        return binary_search_rec(lyst[mid + 1:], target)
```

of course, as mentioned in the comments, you loose the efficiency because you need to create new lists with each call.

Comment: That's great. Thank you. Okay, so for grins, can we say, what if recursion ends up being a constraint? Would I need to include a helper function then? Would I then need to include a helper function that takes in the same things, plus the first and last indices?

Comment: @AaronPrestidge it's almost the same with recursion. See the edit.